# Get client ip on server side with lua

Tags: tcp, lua, ip, esp8266

I want to know the client ip that connects to my lua server to find out if the connection comes from internet or intranet.

```
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
  print(conn)
  conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload)
    ip = conn:getpeername()
    print(ip)
    conn:send("<h1> TEST.</h1>")
  end)
  conn:on("sent",function(conn) conn:close() end)
end)
```

I get the error:

```
PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (stdin:2: attempt to call method 'getpeername' (a nil value))
```

Note: Im using this on the esp8266 chip and I have no experience with lua!

How can I find the IP of the client who connects?

Comment: Which library are you using to establish the connection?

Comment: I dont know... must be implemented in the nodemcu-firmware https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware but it says: Based on Lua 5.1.4 (without debug, os module.)

Comment: Don't use the same variable name in callback function.

Comment: your solution does not fix my problem

Comment: If you can't find the documentation, try exploring the API details. `for k,v in pairs(conn) do print(k,v) end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new patch: ip,port = conn:getpeer() works.

Comment: Maybe it was switched, but the current return set is `port, ip`